# When I decompiled the jar package, I found that one of my methods became fully commented out

Tags: java, jar

Today, after compiling a jar package, I found that a method has lost its function. After decompiling, I found that the code of the corresponding method in the jar package has been completely commented out
I don't know what caused this phenomenon and how to solve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J2Na.png)

Comment: 1. Don't post code in images, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case I think parts of the bytecode will be sufficient. 2. Exactly what did you do to get this? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function is not commented. The compiler failed to reverse this methods so it prints its bytecode.